# Use of "authorities" without the definite article or a possessive pronoun

Tags: nouns, pronouns, zero-article

I have a question about the usage of "authorities" in the following sentence.

> The Kremlin threatened up to 15-year jail sentences for those who report what **authorities** determine to be false information about the use of **its** armed forces.

Could you explain why "authorities" is used without the definite article or a possessive pronoun while "armed forces" is modified with the possessive pronoun?

Comment: A specific "armed forces" is being discussed, while "authorities" refers to those people in general.

Comment: I'd say using 'authorities' without the definite article is an attempt to get the reader to question how valid they are, while the armed forces are hopefully well-regulated. The definite article would often be used before 'authorities' based in say the US.

Comment: I've seen "armed forces" used this way too.  *Sources report that armed forces were involved in border skirmishes over the weekend, but diplomats are still hopeful that the ceasefire will hold.*  I'm not sure how to explain it.  I think it's a super-succinct style common in news reporting.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful replies. These nuances are hard to detect by a non-native speaker like me.

Answer (score 1):

In context, it's obvious that "authorities" refers to some indeterminate group of authorities within Russia, so no possessive pronoun is necessary; since they are referring to some but not all Russian authorities, "its authorities" might even carry incorrect implications.

However, with "armed forces," it is actually necessary to use the possessive. The phrase "the use of armed forces" on its own would mean "the way in which armed forces in general are used," and could thus apply to (say) purely theoretical discussions of military tactics not specific to any country. "The use of *its* armed forces," on the other hand, makes it clear that only information about the Russian military in particular is being censored.